# Android Worker zero argument constructor

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

I get the following error sometimes on some devices:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service
> com.mypackage.service.DownloadDataTaskHandler:
> java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.mypackage.service.DownloadDataTaskHandler>
> has no zero argument constructor
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4204)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.mypackage.service.DownloadDataTaskHandler>
> has no zero argument constructor
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
> at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:75)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4183)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:237) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

The problem is that if I try to create a zero argument constructor in my class I get the error:

> There is no default constructor available in 'androidx.work.Worker'

The code looks like this:

```
public class DownloadDataTaskHandler extends Worker {

Context mContext;

public DownloadDataTaskHandler() {

}

public DownloadDataTaskHandler(
        @NonNull Context context,
        @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
    super(context, params);
    mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
        DownloadIntentService.enqueueWork(getApplicationContext(), new Intent());

    return Result.success();
}
```

}

And the DownloadIntentService extends JobIntentService.

Comment: It says `Class<com.mypackage.service.DownloadDataTaskHandler> has no zero argument constructor`. Does your `DownloadDataTaskHandler` have a zero argument constructor? It is saying that you're trying to create a Service, which has nothing to do with WorkManager.

Comment: Like I wrote, when I try to add thw zero argument constructor (Currently I have none) it gives me the error described above.

Comment: Your error message says says you're trying to start a Service. A Service shouldn't extend `Worker`. Can you explain how you are calling your `DownloadDataTaskHandler` and what you're trying to do?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `JobIntentService` at all when using `WorkManager` - your `Worker` needs to do the work itself. You still haven't included how you are starting your `DownloadDataTaskHandler`. What other code in your app uses that class? Include that code.

Comment: It's being called like this:
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(DownloadDataTaskHandler.class, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .setConstraints(uploadConstraints)
                .build();